# How to maintain the same interval using PlotLegends in ContourPlot?

Tags: plotting, graphics

I want plot results of numerical integration from NDSolveValue:

```
(*Equations*)
h[\[Rho]_, k_][u_, v_] = (\[Rho] u v)/(1 + u + k u^2);
f[a_, \[Rho]_, k_][u_, v_] = a - u - h[\[Rho], k][u, v];
g[\[Alpha]_, b_, \[Rho]_, k_][u_, v_] = \[Alpha] (b - v) - 
   h[\[Rho], k][u, v];

eqns[d_, \[Gamma]_, \[Alpha]_, \[Rho]_, k_, a_, 
   b_] = {Derivative[1, 0, 0][u][t, x, 
      y] - \[Gamma] f[a, \[Rho], k][u[t, x, y], v[t, x, y]] - 
     Inactive[Div][(Inactive[Grad][u[t, x, y], {x, y}]), {x, y}] == 0,
    Derivative[1, 0, 0][v][t, x, 
      y] - \[Gamma] g[\[Alpha], b, \[Rho], k][u[t, x, y], 
       v[t, x, y]] - 
     Inactive[Div][(d Inactive[Grad][v[t, x, y], {x, y}]), {x, y}] == 
    0};
(*Initial Conditions*)

horizontalPeriodicRandomField[{min_, max_}, pts_, L_] := 
 Block[{rand = RandomReal[{min, max}, {pts, pts}]}, 
  rand[[-1]] = rand[[1]];
  ListInterpolation[rand, {{-L, L}, {-L, L}}, 
   PeriodicInterpolation -> {True, False}]]

ics = {u[0, x, y] == 
    horizontalPeriodicRandomField[{0.01, 1}, 100, 5][x, y], 
   v[0, x, y] == 
    horizontalPeriodicRandomField[{0.01, 1}, 100, 5][x, y]};
(*Boundary Conditions*)

bcs = {PeriodicBoundaryCondition[u[t, x, y], x == -5, 
    TranslationTransform[{10, 0}]], 
   PeriodicBoundaryCondition[v[t, x, y], x == -5, 
    TranslationTransform[{10, 0}]]};

(*Solutions*)

Monitor[{ufun, vfun} = 
    NDSolveValue[{eqns[10, 9, 3/2, 37/2, 1/10, 92, 64], bcs, ics}, {u,
       v}, {x, y} \[Element] Rectangle[{-5, -5}, {5, 5}], {t, 0, 1}, 
     Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines", 
         "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
           "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.01}}}}, 
     EvaluationMonitor :> (currentTime = Row[{"t = ", CForm[t]}])];, 
  currentTime];
```

To visualizate 2D spatial for each time step, I have used ContorPlot. I would like to generate distinct snapshots with fixed interval in of PlotLegends, with bottom value fixed in zero and top value in 11.

```
Table[ContourPlot[ufun[t, x, y], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5}, 
  PlotRange -> All, PlotPoints -> 50, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
  ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", PlotTheme -> "Monochrome", 
  PlotLegends -> 
  BarLegend[Automatic, LegendMarkerSize -> 180, LegendLabel -> "u"]], 
  PlotLabel -> Style[" t=" <> ToString[t]]], {t, 0, 1, 0.25}]
```

Note that the PlotLabel associated to spanschots doesn't are fixed between 0 and 11 (only the first is fixed, the others, doesn't). Besides that, there are mistakes as shown below:

[image]

Can anybody help me? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

```
Clear["Global`*"]
```

(*Equations*)

```
h[ρ_, k_][u_, v_] = (ρ u v)/(1 + u + k u^2);
f[a_, ρ_, k_][u_, v_] = a - u - h[ρ, k][u, v];
g[α_, b_, ρ_, k_][u_, v_] = α (b - v) - h[ρ, k][u, v];

eqns[d_, γ_, α_, ρ_, k_, a_, 
   b_] = {Derivative[1, 0, 0][u][t, x, 
      y] - γ f[a, ρ, k][u[t, x, y], v[t, x, y]] - 
     Inactive[Div][(Inactive[Grad][u[t, x, y], {x, y}]), {x, y}] == 0, 
   Derivative[1, 0, 0][v][t, x, 
      y] - γ g[α, b, ρ, k][u[t, x, y], v[t, x, y]] - 
     Inactive[Div][(d Inactive[Grad][v[t, x, y], {x, y}]), {x, y}] == 0};
```

(*Initial Conditions*)

```
horizontalPeriodicRandomField[{min_, max_}, pts_, L_] := 
 Block[{rand = RandomReal[{min, max}, {pts, pts}]}, rand[[-1]] = rand[[1]];
  ListInterpolation[rand, {{-L, L}, {-L, L}}, 
   PeriodicInterpolation -> {True, False}]]

ics = {u[0, x, y] == horizontalPeriodicRandomField[{0.01, 1}, 100, 5][x, y], 
   v[0, x, y] == horizontalPeriodicRandomField[{0.01, 1}, 100, 5][x, y]};
```

(*Boundary Conditions*)

```
bcs = {PeriodicBoundaryCondition[u[t, x, y], x == -5, 
    TranslationTransform[{10, 0}]], 
   PeriodicBoundaryCondition[v[t, x, y], x == -5, 
    TranslationTransform[{10, 0}]]};
```

(*Solutions*)

```
Monitor[{ufun, vfun} = 
    NDSolveValue[{eqns[10, 9, 3/2, 37/2, 1/10, 92, 64], bcs, ics}, {u, 
      v}, {x, y} ∈ Rectangle[{-5, -5}, {5, 5}], {t, 0, 1}, 
     Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"MethodOfLines", 
         "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
           "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.01}}}}, 
     EvaluationMonitor :> (currentTime = Row[{"t = ", CForm[t]}])];, 
  currentTime];
```

The range of `ufun` is

```
{uMin, uMax} =
 (#[{ufun[t, x, y], -5 <= x <= 5, -5 <= y <= 5, 0 <= t <= 1},
     {t, x, y}] & /@ {MinValue, MaxValue})

(* {-0.0566, 9.97146} *)

Manipulate[
 Plot3D[
  ufun[t, x, y], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5},
  PlotRange -> {uMin, uMax},
  PlotPoints -> 100,
  MaxRecursion -> 2],
 {{t, 0}, 0, 1, 0.025, Appearance -> "Labeled"},
 SynchronousUpdating -> False]
```

[image]

For a given value of `t` there is limited variation.

For all of the plots to have a common legend scale

```
legd = BarLegend[{"Rainbow", {uMin, uMax}},
   LegendMarkerSize -> 180,
   LegendLabel -> "u"];

Partition[
   Table[
    {utMin, utMax} =
     NumberForm[#, {5, 2}] & /@
      (#[{ufun[t, x, y], -5 <= x <= 5, -5 <= y <= 5},
          {x, y}] & /@ {MinValue, MaxValue});
    Legended[
     ContourPlot[
      ufun[t, x, y], {x, -5, 5}, {y, -5, 5},
      PlotRange -> All,
      PlotPoints -> 50,
      FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"},
      ColorFunction ->
       (ColorData["Rainbow"][1 - (uMax - #1)/(uMax - uMin)] &),
      ColorFunctionScaling -> False,
      PlotTheme -> "Monochrome",
      PlotLabel -> StringForm["t = ``\n`` <= u <= ``", t, utMin, utMax],
      PlotPoints -> 100,
      MaxRecursion -> 2],
     legd],
    {t, 0, 1, 0.25}],
   UpTo[2]] // Grid // Quiet
```

[image]